# Reinstall mesa from repos

Tags: drivers, debian

I tried to make & install mesa, but things went wrong and my system doesn't found its drivers anymore. How can I reinstall mesa from Debian's repo, to revert to the version used by the installer ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Mesa) , you can install `mesa` as follows :

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```